# How to remove photos from iOS camera roll?

Tags: ios, objective-c

We're working on an app that requires us to take pictures for medical purposes, but to be compliant with HIPAA standards, we can't store the pictures after we've used them. The problem is that when you delete a photo from the camera roll, it moves it to the recently deleted folder, and we need it to be gone for good.

Are there any ways to:

1. Delete photos from the recently deleted folder?
2. Prevent photos from being moved to the recently deleted folder when deleted? or
3. somehow modify the image before deleting (e.g. blacking out the entire image)?

Comment: There's also the issue of iCloud's Photo Stream you might not be aware of too... I don't see how you could make this work given all the hooks into the `iOS`'s own way of dealing with things.

Comment: I notice that `SmartAlbumRecentlyAdded` is one of the PHAssetCollection subtypes but `SmartAlbumRecentlyDeleted` is not. This suggests that perhaps you can't do what you want to do.

Comment: You're not going to be able to programmatically delete the photo entirely. Instead, why don't you create your own camera using `AVFoundation` (the photos taken are not automatically saved to the Camera Roll, or the filesystem at all).