# PHAssetRequestChange deleteAsset does not delete Photo Stream asset as well

Tags: ios, phasset, photostream

In my app, the user can take a photo with a camera, and it will save the image to the camera roll via:

```
PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage
```

I retrieve the PHAsset from this and keep a handle on it. Later on, the user is prompted to decide whether or not they want to delete the photo they took. Using 
the handle on the PHAsset, I delete the PHAsset using:

```
[PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:@[asset]];
```

I get the prompt "Allow 'MYAPP' to delete this photo?". And if you press delete, it deletes it from the camera roll.

However, if the user has Photo Stream enabled, the photo remains in the Photo Stream. Is there anything we can do to remove the Photo Stream image as well?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'm not sure offhand if Apple will allow us to do that or not, check out this post [How to remove photos from iOS camera roll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885416/how-to-remove-photos-from-ios-camera-roll) - Maybe using their suggestion of creating your own camera and saving the file locally instead of in the camera roll so that you don't have to worry about the Photo Stream, then again we don't know the main purpose of your app so it's quite possible you want the photo to be in the Camera Roll.